# Importance of Taylor polynomials

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am reading a book and it says that if $T_n(x)$ is the Taylor polynomial of $f$ of order $n$ at $x=a$ then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{T_n(x)-f(x)}{(x-a)^n} = 0$. In other words, the error is negligible when compared with $(x-a)^n$.

May I ask why the error was compared to $(x-a)^n$ and not with any other function? What's the significance of $(x-a)^n?$

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: It's from Thomas Calculus book. I'm thinking of how to explain to my students why this topic is important.

Comment: What kind of course is this: high school, college, something else?

Comment: it's a first year calculus course for engineers! (I'm a TA) I know how to prove the above result. It just evades me why it's being compared to such a function.

Answer (score 1):

In  Taylor formula  polynomials are used. $(x-a)^n$ is such a polynomial, that its behaviour near $a$ is well-known.

As a result, we can easy obtain important results. For example, if $f'(a)=0$ and $f''(a)>0$ we know, that the function behaves near $a$ as $C(x-a)^2$, where $C$ is positive, hence there is a local minimum in $a$.

Comment: Yes I see but it's the error that's being compared to $(x-a)^n$...

Comment: @TomasJorovic The error ($R_{n+1}$ in the theorem) behaves as $D(x-a)^{n+1}$, hence it is indeed negligible when compared with  $(x-a)^{n}$ (near $a$).